# C++ Builder capture mouse/keyboard messages application (or at least main form) wide?

Tags: c++builder

In C++ Builder, instead of having to setup an event handler for every control on the form (because the control eats the message), is there a way to capture the Mouse Move and Keyboard Down events for the application in one area without having to install hooks?

TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse and keyboard messages are first posted to the main message queue, so you can use the `TApplication.OnMessage` (or `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage`) event to handle `WM_MOUSE(DOWN|MOVE|UP)` and `WM_KEY(DOWN|UP)` messages before they are dispatched to any UI controls.

Comment: And those can easily be setup using the `TApplicationEvents` item from the palette.